# How we can set converted image resolution same as source file in imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I used ImageMagick for Image conversion.It's working fine with image dimension same as source file.But I want Resolution of converted image same as Source file.Here i mentioned sample code.

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readimage(realpath(SOURCE_UPLOAD_PATH.$tmpName));

if($fileType == "psd" || $fileType == "ai" || $fileType == "pdf" || $fileType == "eps"){
    $image->setIteratorIndex(0);
}
$dimensions = $image->getImageGeometry();
$width = $dimensions['width'];
$height = $dimensions['height'];

$image->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
$image->writeImage(realpath(CONVERTED_UPLOAD_PATH)."/". $converted_file_name.".jpg");
```

**Issue**: By this code for ex.i upload .ai file with resolution 96 dpi ,but it convert file with 72 dpi.how i can get converted image dpi same source file?

Comment: You must set the DPI _before_ reading the document, or it'll default to 72. Vector images usually omit any DPI values as that's determined by the rendering device.

Comment: thanks, but if i set dpi to 72, converted image is not same as source image.i want converted image same as source image